# get Value with key from http post response Angular5

Tags: angular

I get this json response from a post:

```
{access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6IC…GYRp73xtCuCE2VtNZqSC7C4N_sDsJoYt_9iaSgLDmpMv70cQw", expires_in: 300, refresh_expires_in: 1800, refresh_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6IC…t-wfBBjgDoitwpiCZVykqZCT2mJvwdRmt1f8OlP7guqDLlJyg", token_type: "bearer", …}
access_token
:
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJidFFTaGZBUDBpazVTTEFTOWZMRE4tbWxXZ3dvRnYwODVPZHpjSUJrWC13In0.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.VceGd7ot7tWQfQ8uScegjcYz1gzOrdEE1som3-PMuyNumV_5qDn44omX3m64NGb5NgT7zgxX1QmeZyKH5i6AG9lG0lvM-u_8zp7tB4kd6i5oNSVQqiBSQmNK7k_Bk5DCIr72epI11W15ZbMYr2siumsTuO5qHkOApIarrgl9B0Cl_sTRMkIhO7S-CltmwkpynNHUEbafPC9bAKx83E4ADOlnlbZSIJnvvVr8aRQ_kAujTlRqRAEXweDkqPS05EFrOGifjKfKLZle3KdK31V0uT-gy2dZyjqflekKkGYRp73xtCuCE2VtNZqSC7C4N_sDsJoYt_9iaSgLDmpMv70cQw"
expires_in
:
300
not-before-policy
:
0
refresh_expires_in
:
1800
refresh_token
:
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJidFFTaGZBUDBpazVTTEFTOWZMRE4tbWxXZ3dvRnYwODVPZHpjSUJrWC13In0.eyJqdGkiOiIwOGUyNjc3ZC02YzNjLTQ5NGUtOGY4OC04MjBjNDk1M2Q5NjQiLCJleHAiOjE1MTk1ODgxMDAsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTE5NTg2MzAwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvZGVtbyIsImF1ZCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsInN1YiI6IjNkYTY2MDYxLTQ2ZjUtNDZmYi1hNjllLTgwNGEzODkyMWQzMiIsInR5cCI6IlJlZnJlc2giLCJhenAiOiJhZG1pbi1jbGkiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjAsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI5YjgxZDVmYy0yZDIwLTQzMzUtODI1Yi1mNzEwOTM3NDBlZTciLCJyZXNvdXJjZV9hY2Nlc3MiOnt9fQ.JG51P9Dxv84jy4LZXuQau9kGS-YoXEfp1gc3CCqUDtM0uupoXN3-zGcrxFQ_0vHrqX4XHqI43aQWAmZtbznXtBOAPoVDkHXsZKnZxYLEag1b9y7aGHMr_psk6T5ckxiij1ge96XGIyn4mRyJgVUv28SOM1IcLb65HskvCmiI23NqE8kwtfKTvYv9DYYqD_eIV7lm4ePTeJiz2v70DEdK_dETR0eBSszabkurLZfjS-tAxC9buL7HE2ZdCATPCMj3mUxjllG329u1JRaEjJjX3nyyPJY_POUaKfkBnt-wfBBjgDoitwpiCZVykqZCT2mJvwdRmt1f8OlP7guqDLlJyg"
session_state
:
"9b81d5fc-2d20-4335-825b-f71093740ee7"
token_type
:
"bearer"
```

I need to get the value of `access_token` but when I do this the value is null:

```
this.http
.post(
    this.ROOT_URL,
    data.toString(), 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
)
//.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
console.log(data.get('access_token'))
}
```

Comment: is data displayed in the console as a result of your call in subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

try this in subscribe method
`let accessToken = data['access_token']`

Answer (score 0):

The code is asynchronous. The `data` is only updated inside the function passed as argument to `.subscribe()`.

Change this:

```
this.http
  .post(
    this.ROOT_URL,
    data.toString(), 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
  )
  //.map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  console.log(data.get('access_token'))
```

Into this:

```
this.http
  .post(
    this.ROOT_URL,
    data.toString(), 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
  )
  //.map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {                          // <== changed this line
    console.log(data);                          // <== changed this line
    console.log(data.get('access_token'));      // <== changed this line
  })
}
```

Not the `console.log(data.get('access_token'))` code will only be executed *after* `data` is available.

**Follow up.** You should really learn about asynchronous code a bit, so you don't get these errors anymore. I suggest [MDN's Promise page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code

1. data.get is not a function, since the return of your ajax call is a plain object. It should be data.access_token or data['access_token']
2. Your console.log it outside of the subscribe block, so data will be null anyway. The console log must be INSIDE the subscribe callback

Try that

```
this.http
.post(
    this.ROOT_URL,
    data.toString(), 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
)
.subscribe(data => 
{
    console.log(data))
    console.log(data.access_token)
});
```